# How to Update Facebook Hashes with Google Play App Sign In

Tags: flutter, google-play

I have Facebook Log In option for my flutter app.

I opted in for Google Play App Sign In.

Now users in production can't sign into the app using Facebook.

The error message is `Invalid key hash xxxxxxxx. The key hash xxxxxxxx does not match any stored key hashes`

So, how can I update the hashes on facebook with the new one received from Google Play App Signing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it, please follow the below steps.

- Go play console and select your app.
- Inside the 'Version' section, click the 'Application Integrity' tab.
- Download the certificate from the button('Download Certificate') to the right of the 'Application signing key certificate' heading.

-- Finally, generate your hash code using the following line of code

```sh
keytool -exportcert -keystore YOUR_DOWNLOADED_CERTIFICATE | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: You saved me. Thank you